# How does uncertainty propagate when a quantity is integrated?

Tags: integration, calculus, error-analysis

Consider a quantity $f(x)$ that has an absolute error $\delta x(x)$. The parentheses indicates that $\delta x$ varies with $x$. What is the uncertainty in $\int_0^x f(x) dx$?

For simplicity let's assume $x$ is known accurately. I found formulae about errors summing two quantities A and B, but I didn't find any reference when A and B were infinitesimals as would be in the case of an integral.

**What am I trying to do:** I have a quantity in a table with columns "$x$", "$f(x)$" and "$\delta(x)$". I am trying to compute the error in $\int_0^x f(x) dx$

Answer (score 0):

The integral is just a fancy way of expressing the sum $\sum f(x_i) \cdot \Delta x_i$, where we commonly assume that the intervals $\Delta x_i$ are equivalent-distantly spaced.  Therefore, a simple and robust method is to use the sum to estimate the error. It might not look fancy, but it certainly is  a straight forward method to estimate the error.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a sum of squared uncertainties? (If uncertainty in this case is proportional to standard deviation)

Comment: Why do you believe that the squared uncertainties are a better approx. to the integral given in the question?

Comment: I should clarify that my comment is expressing a doubt in my knowledge and perhaps you will be able to point out any lack in my reasoning. I thought that if an uncertainty is taken to be the standard deviation of a measurement (may not be the case here) then the uncertainties should be summed in variance space. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25848/how-to-sum-a-standard-deviation

Comment: The link, which you provided https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25848/how-to-sum-a-standard-deviation applies to the sum of two independent random variables, which are normally distributed. However, in particular the independence is questionable in the question we are discussing here: Thus, I strongly recommend taking a conservative approach and to calculate an upper bound of the uncertainty. This is obtained by adding the absolute errors.